# Apply page scrolling on div when mouse is outside div

Tags: jquery, css

I have a `.content` div which has `height: 100%` and `overflow:auto`.
It is the only part of the website that is scrollable.

Now, whenever you try to scroll, and your mouse is outside that div, it won't scroll.
So how do I apply all page scrolling on that div only?

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2zsbf7y0/2/)

Comment: Can you show your CSS stylesheet? I'm curious to see what you have applied to `body` etc. Or paste relevant code into a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: See my updated post for a jsfiddle

Comment: If you want only a portion of the site to scroll, your mouse will have to be over it when you scroll. Otherwise you make the whole site scrollable (as default) and set the non-scrolling elements to `position:fixed`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use mouse events.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WheelEvent

It's fairly easy to take if from there.